# Convert pyspark dataframe to dynamic dataframe

Tags: aws-glue, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe. I was able to convert dynamic dataframe to spark dataframe by `persons.toDF()`. I want to convert the spark dataframe again back to dynamic dataframe in pyspark.I wanted to cast my column to timestamp and again convert it to dynamic dataframe to resolveChoices.
Please help me

Answer (score 4):

at least you need pyspark.context, awsglue.context and awsglue.dynamicframe
There is example :

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)

NewDynamicFrame = DynamicFrame.fromDF(persons, glueContext, "nested")
```

"persons" is your DataFrame

Please check following links  :

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-samples-medicaid.html
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-fromDF

Answer (score 3):

You can create a dynamic frame from dataframe using the fromDF function.

Basic Syntax

```
dyf = fromDF(dataframe, glue_ctx, name)
```

where,

- dataframe – The Apache Spark SQL DataFrame to convert (required).
- glue_ctx – The GlueContext Class object that specifies the context for this transform (required).
- name – The name of the resulting DynamicFrame (required).

Reference : [Dynamic frame from dataframe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-fromDF)